# SaltStack states pattern and replace for multiple files under directory and for multiple line matches

Tags: salt

I am using saltstack state pattern and replace to match a pattern and replace with a new pattern. My init.sls file executes below:

```
`modify_script.sh:
   file.replace:
      - name: /path/to/script.sh
      - pattern: /aaa/bbb
      - repl: /aaa/ccc
      - pattern: /xxx/yyy
      - repl: /xxx/zzz`
```

The above works good if I use a single pattern and replace. This fails for multiple patterns and replaces as shown above. How to achieve multiple pattern replace for two or more patterns in a single file?

Secondly, I have multiple files in a directory which requires a pattern match and replace.

`modify_script.sh:
       file.replace:
          - name: /path/to/dir [having multiple files which require update]
          - pattern: /aaa/bbb
          - repl: /aaa/ccc`

Can I match the patterns for all the files under directory? I wouldn't want to match and replace a single file individually. 
Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Jinja](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/jinja/index.html) to [loop](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#for) over a list of files and pattern/replacement pairs.

```
{% set files = ['/a/foo.sh', '/b/bar.sh', '/b/baz.sh'] %}

{% for file in files %}
{% for p, r in [('/aaa/bbb', '/aaa/ccc'), ('/xxx/yyy', '/xxx/zzz')] %}
replace {{ p }} in {{ file }}:
   file.replace:
      - name: {{ file }}
      - pattern: {{ p }}
      - repl: {{ r }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Keep in mind the identifiers need to be unique, that's why variables in `replace {{ p }} in {{ file }}:` are used.

Comment: A. Z. Thank you, your answer works. However for a variable input under     `{% for p, r in [('/aaa/bbb', '/aaa/{{ var }}'), ('/xxx/yyy', '/xxx/{{ var }}')] %}`
where {{ var }} is a variable defined in jinja, the replacement fails. Can I pass variable input instead of a hardcoded value?